# Maven - custom packaging extension?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

Is it possible to create a maven plugin, which would package my project using a custom file extension? I know that there's a bunch of pre-defined ones like jar, ear, war etc. but I want my own. I also know how to create my own packaging type (using the components.xml), but I still have to tell it what extension it should use.  Do I have to implement my own archiver or something? (basically it will be something like a war but with a different name)

Comment: What kind of extension would you like to have? Isn't the assembly plugin enough?

Comment: well as I said it will be something like a WAR but with a different name (and maybe one or two added things). I think I already found a solution here http://blog.tartachuc.org/2008/07/07/creer-un-packaging-maven2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just as I said in the comment above - it is doable but you need to implement your own archiver (or you can use somehow the existing ones and just rename the resulting file - not sure about this option). It's all described in detail in [this blog](http://blog.tartachuc.org/2008/07/07/creer-un-packaging-maven2).

Comment: translated to [english](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://blog.tartachuc.org/2008/07/07/creer-un-packaging-maven2/&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dblog.tartachuc.org/2008/07/07/creer-un-packaging-maven2%26hl%3Den%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3DPw6%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official&sa=X&ei=JA0tUbDMO-GCjAL4moHYDw&ved=0CEoQ7gEwAA)