# Packaging precompiled binaries for Maven?

Tags: maven

My Java library depends on [Boost C++](http://www.boost.org/). I've generated the following artifact:

boost-maven-project:boost-thread:jar:windows-i386-vs10:1.47.0-b1

where windows-i386-vs10 denotes: "Windows platform, 32-bit architecture, Visual Studio 2010 linker".

I've attempted to upload this to Maven Central but the Sonatype staff [dislikes](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-973?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=135615#comment-135615) the fact that the artifact does not contain a main JAR (only attachment JARs, one per platform).

I don't think that "bundle" packaging is any more appropriate than JAR. Nor do I want to depend on the NAR project (which seems to be inactive). Is there a precedence in the Maven world? What is the best way to package precompiled binaries (without a corresponding Java component)?

Comment: I think you meant to say it does NOT contain a main jar.  And, to elaborate, the reason they're unhappy is because it claims "jar" packaging without having a jar - which seems pretty reasonable to me.  You need to use a custom packaging, methinks - which is exactly what they told you already.

Comment: Maven consists largely of a huge community of independently authored plugins, which work largely because of implicit contracts and assumptions based on, among other things, package type.  The problem isn't that the "Sonatype staff dislikes" it - the problem is that a lot of other tooling will probably break.

Comment: Mh...May be i misunderstand a thing but have you taken a look at the build-helper-maven-plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) ?

Comment: @Ed, you're right. Does *not* contain a main jar. With respect to custom packaging, what do you recommend? I could produce an empty main JAR if need-be. How do other people package native code that does not have corresponding Java code?

Comment: @khmarbaise, doesn't that plugin add attachments to an artifact that already has a main JAR? Mine does not.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327241/maven-custom-packaging-extension) on custom packaging.  Sorry, I've no experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up packaging binaries in JAR files without a main-jar.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so familiar with Maven Central and what the guidelines are to upload artifacts, but we have a local Nexus repository and we upload binaries like dlls as a dll package.
Why should you use a jar package? I think the Sonatype staff is right. Required header files are  attached as a zip file.

Maven has also a C++ plugin, see http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/. Have a look at it. The thoughts of the plugin are really good and should answer a lot of your questions.

By the way I tried to upload myself the Boost libraries into our repository, but I failed. I think the problem was to divide all the Boost headers into different zip files. But I am not sure and I had not the time to find a good solution. If you would make it and the Boost Libraries would be available at Maven Central, I would appreciate this.

Comment: As a side-note, the native-maven-plugin is a total mess. It comes up with yet another file format for native libraries and requires you to specify your native project (build script) in terms of their proprietary format. I ended up using cmake-maven-plugin instead and now I have a sane project file to work and debug with.